# Scroll down with Pentadactyl on DuckDuckGo

Tags: search-engines, vimperator, pentadactyl

I would like to use the DuckDuckGo search engine. But there's an annoying problem that makes it unusable for me:

I use Pentadactyl (the Vimperator fork) with my Firefox. On a fresh DuckDuckGo result page, everything works as it should. But after following a hint and going back (regardless of opening it in a new tab with `F` or the current tab with `f`), I can't scroll down anymore. `j`, `G`, `<Space>`, `<C-f>`... none of them works.

This is not the common problem that embedded elements like the Youtube player steal focus and Pentadactyl is not receiving any keystrokes. Other commands like another `f` or even scrolling up (`k`, `gg`...) still work!

I can solve this by clicking somewhere on the page with the mouse. But of course this is exactly what should be avoided by Pentadactyl.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should be able to regain navigation simply by hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
- Alternatively, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> will put you in [passthrough mode](http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/browsing.xhtml#bypassing-pentadactyl), disabling pentadactyl bindings. You can then use the the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys to navigate between results (I assume these keybindings are implemented by the site). These bindings are actually more convenient for scrolling through the results anyway.

Comment: <kbd>Tab</kbd> did the trick, thank you! However, I don't understand, what happens exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but it looks like scrolling is disabled when the focus is on one of the main result links (it doesn't happen on the smaller links underneath). When you hit `j`, it tries (pointlessly) to scroll the link _within_ the result, rather than scrolling the page as a whole. Hitting `TAB` moves the focus to the next link (the small icon for site: search), which doesn't cause the issue. If you hit tab a couple more times, you'll focus the next big link and the navigation will break again. I'd be interested in a more detailed explanation myself.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't it strange that scrolling up works while scrolling down doesn't? Doesn't make sense to me.
Funny enough, this issue only appears on my Linux Mint (Cinnamon Desktop), not on my Arch (Enlightenment or KDE Desktop), both with the same Firefox and Pentadactyl version.

Answer (score 0):

Would `strictfocus` be of help?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pentadactyl/lmY8rKtqI8g

Comment: Unfortunately not. But thanks anyway, I didn't know that option.